# php add array with the same values

Tags: php

i have this array in PHP and i want to sum the values of the same arrays.

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "days" => 1
    "price" => 4000
    "cost" => 4000
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "days" => 1
    "price" => 3000
    "cost" => 3000
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "days" => 1
    "price" => 3000
    "cost" => 3000
  ]
]
```

I am gonna have this code:

```
array:2 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "days" => 1
    "price" => 4000
    "cost" => 4000
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "days" => 2
    "price" => 6000
    "cost" => 6000
  ]
]
```

how can i achieve that?

Comment: Dude, why change the question? Now it does not make any sense...

Comment: @Brainfeeder its reverted now..can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very time or memory efficient, but working:

```
$results = [];

// create a two dimensional array to collect all arrays which are the same
$collection = [];
foreach ($input as $elem) {
    $collection[serialize($elem)][] = $elem;
}

// create the result array
foreach ($collection as $elems) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($elems[0] as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key] = $value * count($elems);
    }
    $results[] = $result;
}

print_r($results);
```

(assuming your array comes in $input)

Comment: Thanks! It Works!

Comment: What if i want to sum only the days and cost and leave the price as its initial value? (3000 in above code)

Comment: Why do you want to "sum the values of the same arrays" in the first place? What do you want to solve? Do you want to group the same items in a Shopping Cart or the like? If yes "the same array" is not a good criterion for grouping. Maybe you need something like an article-ID next to cost and days.